# Count specific pattern in URLs bigquery sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I got a table which contains URLs and some other columns, for example dates. The URLs contain IDs, separated by different values. What the IDs have in common is that they contain only numeric values [0-9] and are separated by non-numeric characters:

```
date | url
01-01-1999 | https://www.example.com/category1/subcategory1/71347983~7275798_fui~85092374238590235.......
01-02-1999 | https://www.example.com/category1/subcategory2/71347983_7275798/85092374238590235~773429834.......
01-02-1999 | https://www.example.com/category1/subcategory2/71347983_23235~773429834.......
01-01-1999 | https://www.example.com/category2/subcategory1/71347983_7275798_85092374238590235~773429834-1378162468.......
01-01-1999 | https://www.example.com/category2/subcategory2/71347983........
01-01-1999 | https://www.example.com/category2/subcategory2/45256........
```

Note: the amount of IDs per URl differs
Note: IDs differ in length
Note: IDs are separated by different characters
Note: IDs are not always at the third level in the URLs

I'd like to construct a query that counts the amount of ID's in the URL. The query should return something like:

```
date | #IDs
01-01-1999 | 4
01-02-1999 | 4
01-02-1999 | 3
01-01-1999 | 5
01-01-1999 | 1
01-01-1999 | 1
```

Secondly, I'd like to group the "amounts" by date:

```
date | #IDs | amount date/ID combination
01-01-1999 | 4 | 1
01-02-1999 | 4 | 1
01-02-1999 | 3 | 1
01-01-1999 | 5 | 1
01-01-1999 | 1 | 2
```

The part of identify an ID is something that I am not manage to get working. Should I work with regex? Or something else? Hope someone could help me out!

Comment: Can you better define `amount date/ID combination`?

Answer (score 0):

I see that in one of your examples IDs can be separated by `/` too. If you know the maximum number of "levels" (number of `/` in your path). You can use this query to extract all the IDs.

```sql
with url_parts as (
    select
    date,
    split(url, '/') as parts
    from table
)
select
    date,
    regexp_extract_all(url_parts[safe_offset(5)], "\d") level_3,
    regexp_extract_all(url_parts[safe_offset(6)], "\d") level_4,
    ...,
    regexp_extract_all(url_parts[safe_offset(n)], "\d") level_n-2
from  url_parts
```

You can build on top of this to do more aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
select
    date,
    ids_count,
    count(*) as combinations_count
from
    (   select
            date,
            url,
            regexp_extract_all(
                concat(
                    regexp_replace(url, r'[[:punct:]]', '~~'), '~'),
                r'~(\d+)~') as ids,

            array_length(
                regexp_extract_all(
                    concat(
                        regexp_replace(url, r'[[:punct:]]', '~~'), '~'),
                    r'~(\d+)~')) as ids_count
        from
            unnest(array[   struct(date'1999-01-01' as date, 'https://www.example.com/category1/subcategory1/71347983~7275798_fui~85092374238590235.......' as url),
                            struct(date'1999-01-02', 'https://www.example.com/category1/subcategory2/71347983_7275798/85092374238590235~773429834.......'),
                            struct(date'1999-01-01', 'https://www.example.com/category1/subcategory2/71347983_23235~773429834')])
    )
group by
    1, 2
```

Comment: `[[:punct:]]` is shortcut for [!-/:-@[-`{-~]

Comment: or you can use all of them [!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]

Comment: or `regexp_replace(url, r'[^[:alnum:]]', '~~')` (replace anything that is not alphanumeric) instead of `regexp_replace(url, r'[[:punct:]]', '~~')`

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> I'd like to construct a query that counts the amount of ID's in the URL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date, 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(1)  
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(url, r'[^[:punct:]]+')) part 
    WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(part, r'[^\d]')
  ) IDs
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question  - the output is

```
Row date        IDs 
1   01-01-1999  3        
2   01-02-1999  4        
3   01-02-1999  3        
4   01-01-1999  5        
5   01-01-1999  1        
6   01-01-1999  1
```

> Secondly, I'd like to group the "amounts" by date

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date, IDs, COUNT(1) combinations FROM (
  SELECT date, 
    (
      SELECT COUNT(1)  
      FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(url, r'[^[:punct:]]+')) part 
      WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(part, r'[^\d]')
    ) IDs
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
GROUP BY date, IDs
```

If to apply to sample data from your question  - the output is

```
Row date        IDs combinations     
1   01-01-1999  3   1    
2   01-02-1999  4   1    
3   01-02-1999  3   1    
4   01-01-1999  5   1    
5   01-01-1999  1   2
```